# Unable to pin Google chrome to taskbar on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome

It seems like Google Chrome is not able to be pinned at taskbar on Kubuntu.

[image: Pin checkbox is invalidated]

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can pin/unpin Google Chrome without issues.

Pinning

[image: Pinning Google Chrome]

Unpin option

[image: Unpin option]

It's possible something has gone wrong on your system.

Can you pin Google Chrome successfully if you set up a new user account?

To set up a new user account, open *System Settings > Account Details > User Manager > New User*.

Comment: Actually I just reinstalled the google chrome and now it became pin-able :)

Comment: @Jaebum - you can also add it as widget: search it in the Application Launcher, right click (widgets have to be un-locked)